# Passing Strings from listview that has not been populated

Tags: android, string, listview

I would like to pass `String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";`  `String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";` and also `String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";` but when I click on an item that I want, the only string that displays in the next activity is `String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";` The reason for this is because that is the only string that is populating the listview. I do not want the other two strings to be populated in the listview, I just want to pass them into the next activity so they can be displayed there. Can anybody show me a way to pass these two other strings without populating them.

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {    


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
     final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "content";      
     final String TAG_QUERY = "query";

            JSONArray question = null;          
            android.widget.ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

    questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 


    new LoadAllData().execute();

        }

    @Override   
    protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
         super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);  

         String Subject = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Subject)).getText().toString();
         String Content = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Content)).getText().toString();
         String ChosenAnswer = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ChosenAnswer)).getText().toString();


         Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
         i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
         i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
         i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);
         startActivity(i);

            }     


    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        private Dialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog pDialog; 
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {

                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String NumAnswers = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                    //JSONArray Answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);


                    //JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(0);

                    //String Content = Answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                               questionList.add(map);


                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_QUESTION ;           

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.listelements,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers, });

                setListAdapter(adapter); 


        }}}
```

SingleListItem Activity:

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity {

    TextView title;
    TextView question;
    TextView bestanswer;
    TextView subject;
    TextView content;
    TextView chosenanswer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.singlelistitem);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title1);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question1);
    bestanswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BestAnswer1);
    subject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Subject1);
    content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Content1);
    chosenanswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ChosenAnswer1);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String Subject = i.getStringExtra("Subject");
    String Content = i.getStringExtra("Content");
    String ChosenAnswer = i.getStringExtra("ChosenAnswer");
    subject.setText(Subject);
    content.setText(Content);
    chosenanswer.setText(ChosenAnswer);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your data model in such cases. The code below should work for you.

```
@Override   
protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);  

  HashMap<String, String> item = questionList.get(pos);

  Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
  i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT));
  i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT));
  i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER));
  startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your assist but I forgot to post the activity that will receive these strings and I just wondering will it still receive the data with the way I have set it up(Activity is in updated question)